# html tag has 28px to margin which seems to come from nowhere

Tags: css

I'm getting this top margin from `alexchen.info #2`. I'm not sure what's that. It is not my CSS file (`style.css`).

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure what other information provide. Any suggestions?

Comment: It says it's `!important`.  So it could be coming from any CSS file the site is using.  Can you do a text search through all the files in your CSS directory for `!important`?

Comment: @Robert Harvey I checked them all, it doesn't seem to come from a CSS file.

Comment: Are you using Wordpress?  See [this Google search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=margin-top+28px+important)

Comment: Check whether it's applied inline on the page itself. Do you have a test page we can look at?

Comment: @JohnP Original file or HTML output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's most likely the space taken up by the admin bar introduced in WordPress 3.1. I don't know why they'd put an admin bar on the frontend and not the admin page, but that's how it is.

Go to your admin profile page and you can turn it off from there (or enable it only on the admin panel).

See also http://wordpress.org/support/topic/margin-top-added-to-html-and-body-tags-after-upgrade-to-31

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `html{ margin-top: 0 !important; }` in the last line of the last CSS document linked to..